# How to not create channel if one exist with same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is a simple script that creates a channel, but i don't want to to create that channel if there's another channel already with the same name of this channel the bot is creating

```
servr = message.server
            await client.create_channel(servr, 'Channel_name', type=discord.ChannelType.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) to iterate though the channels of the server checking their names

```
server = message.server
name = 'Channel_name'
if not get(server.channels, name=name)
    await client.create_channel(server, name, type=discord.ChannelType.text)
```

Comment: "get isn't defined" it says

Comment: You have to import it `from discord.utils import get`